# Is it RAM issue while Building Android AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I am on core i5 400 GB SSD and 16 GB RAM with 6 cores.

I an getting this error while building Android AOSP.

```
    FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
    cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp

Killed
06:18:08 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:17 (mm:ss)) ####
```

this is build.go logs :

```
build.go:166: Total RAM: 15.6GB
build.go:169: ************************************************************
build.go:170: You are building on a machine with 15.6GB of RAM
build.go:171:
build.go:172: The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
build.go:173: and even with that, some configurations may not work.
build.go:174:
build.go:175: If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
build.go:176: -j value.
build.go:177: ************************************************************
```

How can i fix this? I have tried make , make -j6 , -j1 and -j4 options already after make clobber

Answer (score 1):

yes, likely you build android 12,follow this guide to disable low memory terminate

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701605

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out it was due to low RAM issue.
So I followed this : https://groups.google.com/g/android-building/c/5G2l5JR3jWE
to change the zram swap size .
The OP claim to build android on 8 GB RAM as well with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

32GB RAM is recommended for the building, ignore whatever the log say!